# Sharepoint Standard Edition how to resolve Infopath Error?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-standard

We are using Standard edition of sharepoint. In infopath form we are receiving the following error.(The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server)

[image]

If SharePoint is enterprise edition in Central Admin--->General Application Settings--->Configure Info path Forms Services if we are changing the Data Connection Response Size this error will go.

But Standard edition this option is not there in Central admin.How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

**First,** You should be aware of the InfoPath Forms service is only supported in SharePoint Enterprise Edition.

So you can't find the same Infopath setting in Central Administration For SharePoint Standard.

> **Note:** Only the Workflow InfoPath Forms is supported in SharePoint Standard!

**Second,** regarding your error The Default data connection response size is `1500kb`, If the response size from the data connection exceeds the default limit you will get this error

> "The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has
>   exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server
>   administrator."

It looks like you have customized the Workflow InfoPath form to pull a lot of data, and in this case, you should remove the unnecessary fields to pull less data!

Comment: its possible to change Default data connection response size  in Infopath Designer

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no setting in InfoPath Designer related to data connection response size,  it should be server set not form set!

Comment: there is any other way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Based on my humble knowledge, the available solution for SharePoint standard is what I have mentioned in the above answer! or upgrade your license to SharePoint EnterPrise Edition!

Comment: can you confirm me this error will come based on task list item count or workflow history count ?

Comment: To can confirm, Please tell me first what's the customization that you have done in your workflow form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67276/discussion-between-elina-and-m-qassas).

Comment: Not sure if the PowerShell CmdLet is available in Standard Edition? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608034(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: It is mentioned in the link that it applies to SharePoint Enterprise 2013! meanwhile, try to check it as `Set-SPInfoPathFormsService -MaxDataConnectionResponseSize 30000`

Comment: Poweshell script is working in standard edition also.Issue get resolved Thank you so much.